# Move view to bottom of screen with translationY

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got a view in my app that is moved around with translationY and I'm trying to add an option to move it to the bottom of the screen by getting the screen size of the device, but the behaviour is really inconsistent across devices, with it working perfectly on various Pixel phones, but disappearing off the screen entirely on OnePlus phones and some high-res Samsung phones, but being too high up on low-res phones.

All I'm doing is getting the screen height, subtracting the height of the view and the height of the navbar and setting that to its location:

```
var barHeight = 0
var metrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
var size = metrics.heightPixels

return size - barHeight - getNavigationBarHeight()
```

here's getNavigationBarHeight too:

```
var metrics = DisplayMetrics()
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
var usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
var realHeight = metrics.heightPixels
if (realHeight > usableHeight)
    return realHeight - usableHeight
else
    return 0
```

but it never seems to be perfectly at the bottom. Is this just a quirk of DisplayMetrics or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest programmatically aligning the view to the bottom of the screen with `NavigationBar`s height as `marginBottom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer about displayMetrics, always had a hunch that the device can freely provide whatever values it wants to. For example, some devices might include the height of the navigation bar, some may not. I thought it would be consistent throughout major manufacturers, but judging from what you are saying about OnePlus it seems they are not.

Why don't you use a ConstraintLayout with different ConstraintSets? That's the best and easiest way to make animations. MotionLayouts are also a choice, if you don't mind using the Android Studio 4.1.

A nice article about ContraintLayout animations: https://proandroiddev.com/creating-awesome-animations-using-constraintlayout-and-constraintset-part-i-390cc72c5f75

Comment: The toolbar is a ConstraintLayout, so I'll give this a go. I'm not currently using Android Studio 4 due to issues with VCS, but I can use it to edit the project files.